# How to cancel Windows 10 installer update rollback?

Tags: 8.1, windows-10-mobile, insider-preview

I am using a Lumia 535. I installed Windows 10 Technical Preview. I then did a rollback to Windows 8.1.

My question is:

After the roll back, while restarting, it always displays the Windows 10 Technical Preview available update message. Sometimes it automatically downloads and uses some of my data.

How do I fix this issue with my Windows Phone?

Comment: Have you used the insider app to un-enroll the phone from the insider program?

Comment: i am using "Windows Phone Recovery Tool" for rollback the OS.

Comment: i referred this ULR http://www.windowscentral.com/roll-back-windows-phone-81-windows-10-preview

Comment: When you rolled back to 8.1, did you restore settings, apps, etc from a backup? and is the Windows Insider app installed?

Comment: no that time, its automatically deleted. all settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got answer for this issue. after reset the phone its working fine. and also not ask preview available message. Thank u all